# wxPython popup window bound to a wxButton

Tags: python, wxpython, popupwindow

I've been looking around, browsing a whole bunch of different sites and I'm unable to find how to create a popupwindow for a wxButton in wxPython.

Any ideas how?

Comment: What do you mean by "popup window"?  Do you want a new window to open when the user presses a button? Or are you looking for something more like tool text which shows up when a user mouses over the button?

Comment: I'd like a new window to popup over the other one.

Comment: Is this new window something you created? (i.e. you have a class for it)

Comment: Yes, I've made a new class. I'm just unsure of how to bind it.

Comment: Can you post a shortened version of your class? How to make it show depends on how you built it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you look at the wxPython demo? It has several examples of using wx.PopupWindow and its variants. Here's an example based on the demo:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class TestPopup(wx.PopupWindow):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, style):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.PopupWindow.__init__(self, parent, style)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel = panel
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("CADET BLUE")

        st = wx.StaticText(panel, -1,
                           "This is a special kind of top level\n"
                           "window that can be used for\n"
                           "popup menus, combobox popups\n"
                           "and such.\n\n"
                           "Try positioning the demo near\n"
                           "the bottom of the screen and \n"
                           "hit the button again.\n\n"
                           "In this demo this window can\n"
                           "be dragged with the left button\n"
                           "and closed with the right."
                           ,
                           pos=(10,10))
        sz = st.GetBestSize()
        self.SetSize( (sz.width+20, sz.height+20) )
        panel.SetSize( (sz.width+20, sz.height+20) )

        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseLeftDown)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMotion)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseLeftUp)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.OnRightUp)

        st.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseLeftDown)
        st.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMotion)
        st.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseLeftUp)
        st.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.OnRightUp)

        wx.CallAfter(self.Refresh)    

    def OnMouseLeftDown(self, evt):
        self.Refresh()
        self.ldPos = evt.GetEventObject().ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
        self.wPos = self.ClientToScreen((0,0))
        self.panel.CaptureMouse()

    def OnMouseMotion(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            dPos = evt.GetEventObject().ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
            nPos = (self.wPos.x + (dPos.x - self.ldPos.x),
                    self.wPos.y + (dPos.y - self.ldPos.y))
            self.Move(nPos)

    def OnMouseLeftUp(self, evt):
        if self.panel.HasCapture():
            self.panel.ReleaseMouse()

    def OnRightUp(self, evt):
        self.Show(False)
        self.Destroy()

########################################################################
class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Open Popup")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onShowPopup)


    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onShowPopup(self, event):
        """"""
        win = TestPopup(self.GetTopLevelParent(), wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

        btn = event.GetEventObject()
        pos = btn.ClientToScreen( (0,0) )
        sz =  btn.GetSize()
        win.Position(pos, (0, sz[1]))

        win.Show(True)

########################################################################
class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test Popup")
        panel = TestPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = TestFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even see that one.